# How to verify SSMParameter creation in stack?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am working to create aws resources using cdk library and able to create the resources succesfully. Now I want to write test case to verify correctness of CloudFormation.

Following is piece of code which creates SSM paramte.

```
export class SSMParamaters extends cdk.Construct {

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: SSMParamatersProps) {
    super(scope, id);
    
    const param = new ssm.StringParameter(this, "testSSM", {
      parameterName: props.envName,
      stringValue: String(props.envValue),
    });
  }
}
```

Following is the test for the same. But not sure this is the correct way to test its.
Can someone help me on this?

```
test('Test sqs type ssmParameter', () => {
  
  const app = new App();
  const testSqsStack = new Stack(app, 'TestSQSStack');
  let ssmParam = new SSMParamaters(test, 'test-param',
    {
      envName: 'Home',
      envValue: '/home/test'
    });

  expect(() => ssmParam).toHaveResource("test-sqs-param");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDK's [testing constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html) let us assert against the synth-ed JSON CloudFormation stack template output.  Resource types (`AWS::SSM::Parameter`) and property names (`Value`, not `value`!) need to match the template's JSON formats.

For instance, your stack's template output in `cdk.out` will include something like this:

```json
// MyStack.template.json
{
  "Resources": {
    "FooParameter23C8BF74": {
      "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
      "Properties": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Value": "/home/test",
        "Name": "Home"
      },
```

Using the OP's `@aws-cdk/assert` module syntax, you assert the presence of a `ssm.Parameter` like this:

```js
// MyStack.test.ts
test('test SSM', () => {
  const app = new cdk.App();
  const stack = new SimpleSsmStack(app, 'SsmStack', {});

  // matches if present in the JSON stack template
  expect(stack).toHaveResource('AWS::SSM::Parameter');

  // optionally match specific resource properties
  expect(stack).toHaveResource('AWS::SSM::Parameter', { Name: 'Home', Value: '/home/test' });
});
```

Note:  the `@aws-cdk/assert` module [is deprecated](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/@aws-cdk/assertions/MIGRATING.md).  The current assertions module is [aws-cdk-lib/assertions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions-readme.html), which has different syntax:

```js
// MyStack.test.ts
import { Template } from 'aws-cdk-lib/assertions';
// ...
  const template = Template.fromStack(stack);
  template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::SSM::Parameter', { Name: 'Home', Value: '/home/test' });
```